# Best structure for xna Arcade Game

Tags: xna-4.0

I need to design an arcade game using XNA.
This will has 9 different game where the player can select one of them.
I want to do it the best clear and separated as possible. For easy maintenance.
These game will share a common credit.
Is possible to do it as DLL each game and call them from a main Project?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to manage multiple things (screens, levels) is to make a GameComponent. You can attach them to your base game (Probably Game1?) and then you can toggle their visibility and active states. Microsoft has some good info on it.

Good luck! :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamecomponent.aspx